# How to make a column from pandas dataframe into a list at each ROW?

Tags: python, json, pandas, list, dataframe

Currently I have a JSON file that I converted from pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
{"My Setting": {
        "0": {
            "upper limit": "120",
            "lower limit": "40",
            "ID": "2000333",
            "Competitor ID": "99123"
        },
        "1": {
            "upper limit": "100",
            "lower limit": "30",
            "ID": "2444555",
            "Competitor ID": "99456"
        }
    }
}
```

I need the ID and Competitor ID to be in list values, so the JSON file should look like this:

```
{"My Setting": {
        "0": {
            "upper limit": "120",
            "lower limit": "40",
            "ID": ["2000333"],
            "Competitor ID": ["99123"]
        },
        "1": {
            "upper limit": "100",
            "lower limit": "30",
            "ID": ["2444555"],
            "Competitor ID": ["99456"]
        }
    }
}
```

I can only find tolist() which makes a column into a list but not inside the dataframe.

Is there anyway I can make those 2 columns into list values and then convert into JSON file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the values as lists after converting the dataframe to dictionary. For example:

```py
dct = {
    "My Setting": {
        "0": {
            "upper limit": "120",
            "lower limit": "40",
            "ID": "2000333",
            "Competitor ID": "99123",
        },
        "1": {
            "upper limit": "100",
            "lower limit": "30",
            "ID": "2444555",
            "Competitor ID": "99456",
        },
    }
}

for v in dct.values():
    for vv in v.values():
        vv["ID"] = [vv["ID"]]
        vv["Competitor ID"] = [vv["Competitor ID"]]

print(dct)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "My Setting": {
        "0": {
            "upper limit": "120",
            "lower limit": "40",
            "ID": ["2000333"],
            "Competitor ID": ["99123"],
        },
        "1": {
            "upper limit": "100",
            "lower limit": "30",
            "ID": ["2444555"],
            "Competitor ID": ["99456"],
        },
    }
}
```

---

OR: To convert a column of values to column of lists:

```py
df["column"] = df["column"].apply(lambda x: [x])
```

and then convert the dataframe to Json.

Comment: How would you make individual elements in the list inside a [ ] too? What I am trying to achieve is from "ID": "2444555", "2827474" to  "ID": [ ["2444555"], ["2827474"] ]

Comment: @NicoleL I recommend to open a new question here on stackoverflow where you put sample input, expected output and what have you tried so far.

Comment: Hi Andrej, I just posted another question, would you mind answering it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74453260/how-to-turn-a-cell-of-dataframe-into-list-of-list-when-another-cell-does-not-eq