# How to turn a cell of dataframe into list of list, when another cell does not equals to a certain value?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframe

```
Consideration_level    |  Consideration_value
-------------------------------------------------
Car_ID                        00111
Car_ID                        00222
Car_type, Location            Jeep, NYC
Car_Color, Location           Pink, BOS
```

I want to turn it into

```
Consideration_level    |  Consideration_value
-------------------------------------------------
Car_ID                        [00111]
Car_ID                        [00222]
Car_type, Location            [[Jeep], [NYC]]
Car_Color, Location           [[Pink], [BOS]]
```

So essentially, I want when the Consideration_level does NOT equal to "Car_ID", the Consideration_value should be a list of list; when Consideration_level equals to "Car_ID", the Consideration_value would be one single list.

I tried

## list into a list of lists

def extractDigits(lst):
return [[el] for el in lst]

But I don't know how to do the logic here... Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below answers :

i have used [map](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-map-function/) and [lambda](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-lambda-anonymous-functions-filter-map-reduce/) function

**Solution**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
Consideration_level=['Car_ID','Car_ID','Car_type, Location','Car_type, Location']
Consideration_value=['00111','00222','Jeep, NYC','Pink, BOS']
data_dict = {'Consideration_level':Consideration_level,
            'Consideration_value':Consideration_value}

df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)

df['Consideration_value'] = list(map(lambda CL : list(CL) if CL == 'Car_ID' else \
                                     np.array(list(CL.split(","))).reshape(-1,1).tolist(),\
                                     df['Consideration_value']))
df
```

**Output**

```
    Consideration_level Consideration_value
0   Car_ID                 [[00111]]
1   Car_ID                  [[00222]]
2   Car_type, Location  [[Jeep], [ NYC]]
3   Car_type, Location  [[Pink], [ BOS]]
```